# DataBindingInfo.java being regenerated at every code change

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, android-gradle-3.0, kapt

I'm working on fairly large, multi module Android project which is using Data Binding, Dagger 2 and Java mixed with Kotlin.

After the slightest change in the project "code" files (.java and .kt files including activities, custom classes etc) there is a huge (up to 2 minutes) build time. It happens even when I'm adding changes like a new line or modify one character in comment.

I did run Gradle script with --info parameter and got the following hint, it "hangs" on the following task:

> Build cache key for task ':AppName:kaptDebugKotlin' is
>   1a3a53e5f9b0934ab50a25c0133055f2 Up-to-date check for task
>   ':AppName:kaptDebugKotlin' took 0.0 secs. It is not up-to-date
>   because:   Input property 'source' file
>   /Users/username/Android/project-directory/AppName/build/generated/source/dataBinding/debug/android/databinding/layouts/DataBindingInfo.java
>   has changed.   Input property 'source' file
>   /Users/username/Android/project-directory/AppName/src/main/java/com/package/to/my/activity/SomeActivity.java
>   has changed.

The DataBindingInfo.java is generated file which contains just a buildId:

```
package android.databinding.layouts;

import android.databinding.BindingBuildInfo;

@BindingBuildInfo(buildId="23567c57-d3c8-4999-bc79-6211351c7d89")
public class DataBindingInfo {}
```

And the buildId hash changes each time there is any change in the code.

The project uses Crashlytics, I disabled it for debug builds though.

What might be the cause of this behaviour?

EDIT: buildId is getting regenerated on the project even when the Android Studio is closed and I'm doing the changes in the external editor and running builds from command line.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `Reference Code generated from compiler` option? Go to Settings -> Editor -> Data Binding -> Reference Code generated from compiler -> Apply  and then Restart your Android studio

Comment: Thanks @Sagar I've tried, same thing is happening. This issue also occurs without Android Studio involvement, while I modify the files in external editor and build it from command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Android Gradle's automatic buildId update using the code below for the debug (or other debug variants if you want).

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Already set in the project, unfortunately doesn't help in this particular case...